# Why is there a exc_breakpoint?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview nib on a viewcontroller in a storyboard so I can perform segues. Currently I have placed the first nib on a viewcontroller, but when I do `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and segue to another viewcontroller I get a `exc_breakpoint` error.

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let concerts = arrayOfConcerts[indexPath.row]
    let artistconcert: ArtistConcerts = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("concertartist") as! ArtistConcerts
    print(indexPath.row)
    self.presentViewController(artistconcert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //artistconcert.
}
```

Below is the code for the ArtistConcerts

```
class ArtistConcerts: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableartist: UITableView!
var arrayOfArtists: [concert] = [concert]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setUpArtists()
    self.loadViewFromNib()
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "LiveConcerts", bundle: nil)
    tableartist.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
 func loadViewFromNib(){
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ArtistsConcerts", owner: self, options: nil)
    print("in viewcontroller")
}

func setUpArtists(){
    let Strokes = concert(imageName: "")
    arrayOfArtists.append(Strokes)

}
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfArtists.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableartist.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let artists = arrayOfArtists[indexPath.row]

    cell.setCell(artists.imageName)

    return cell

   }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the error message you are receiving.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxh6fki6abeguv9/Screenshot%202015-10-08%2008.11.37.png?dl=0

Comment: Ignore the red underline, that is not the error.

Comment: But what is the warning and why is it not fixed?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3jixwj43bvq1sd/Screenshot%202015-10-08%2008.27.05.png?dl=0

Comment: It goes away after I clean and run it, but the exc_breakpoint is still occuring

Comment: Hint for sharing error messages: Apple does not allow them to be copied but there is a way. Go to the report navigator, expose the error (some disclosure chicking may be required). YOu sill can not copy the error message but you can drag the error message to an area that accepts text area including a SO question/comment field.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind, but do you know why it is crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have crash on line 
`let artistconcert: ArtistConcerts = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("concertartist") as! ArtistConcerts`

Are you sure, that you have a view controller in storyboard with indetifier `concertartist` and correct module name.

Comment: I def have a storyboard identifier  `concertartist`, what do you mean module name? https://www.dropbox.com/s/4g4jfoa5hzynfbe/Screenshot%202015-10-08%2008.16.03.png?dl=0

Comment: @blee on the screenshot Module Current - Musec select this one

Answer (score 0):

Change `self.storyboard` which is optional on

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

Comment: This is the log when it crashes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/06i72o6bw634n73/Screenshot%202015-10-08%2010.13.09.png?dl=0